# Python- bottle - cookies keep changing

Tags: python, cookies, setcookie, bottle

Below is my code for setting and reading cookies in bottle.

```
if request.get_cookie('mycookiename'):
        cookie_id = request.get_cookie('mycookiename')
    else:
        cookie_id=str(uuid4())
        response.set_cookie('mycookiename', cookie_id , max_age=31556952*2, domain='%s' % (cookie_domain))
```

When I go to firefox and firebug, I can see that the cookie is set.  But, when I refresh the page, I get a new cookie.  Every request is a new cookie id.

So, how do I resolve?

Comment: Are you trying to implement sessions? [Beaker](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9248245/241039) sessions would probably be better.

Comment: persistent cookies for two years.

Answer (score 1):

This code works. You set a new value cookie with uuid4 if you have not a cookie already define.

In your code, i guess your "else" condition is bad.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python
from uuid import uuid4
import bottle

@bottle.route('/cookie')
    def cookie():
        cookie_id = bottle.request.get_cookie('mycookiename', str(uuid4()))
        bottle.response.set_cookie('mycookiename', cookie_id)
        return 'hello cookie'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```